# How to exclude fields when using Django _meta.get_fields()

Tags: python, django

My model has the standard "id" field, and I would like to exclude it when I use _meta.get_fields(). My current solution looks something like this:

```
context_var = (MyModel._meta.get_fields())[1:]
```

It works well enough, but I don't really like the slice solution. I'd rather remove the id field by name, or use a method that explicitly excludes the id field. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
context_var = [f for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if f.name != 'id']
```

Comment: If you want to exclude several fields try: ```[f for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if f.name not in  ['id', 'some_thing', 'another_thing']]```

Comment: @nik_m **Thank you!**

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can use Python's built-in [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```py
In [1]: context_var = filter(lambda x: x.name != 'id', MyModel._meta.fields)

In [2]: type(context_var)
Out[2]: filter

In [3]: for item in context_var: print(item)

MyModel.field1
MyModel.field2
...
```

The resulting value is of type `filter` which you can iter through, but, depending on what you need to do with `context_var` later, you might want to convert it into a tuple:

```py
In [4]: context_var = tuple(filter(lambda x: x.name != 'id', MyModel._meta.fields))
```